# A word to describe "a shy smile after stupid mistakes"

Tags: word-request

Which word can I use to describe a smile which someone gives after making a stupid mistake?

I want to describe the smile of a TV news anchor, when the camera catches her combing her hair.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would [very often](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that%20would%20be%22%20%22please%20sir%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22sheepish%20smile%22&oq=%22sheepish%20smile%22&gs_l=serp.3...7041.9529.6.9829.9.9.0.0.0.0.77.482.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.OTFQ_p0LPho&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916) be described as a *[sheepish](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=sheepish&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=vM2sUbuUIYmA0AWW4oAo&ved=0CCwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=62ecb0084cfd0724&biw=1292&bih=916) smile*.

> (of a person or expression) Showing embarrassment from shame or a lack of self-confidence
>   e.g. *- a sheepish grin.*

Answer (score 0):

Think of something better just for shy like:
bashful
diffident
farouche
timid]
sheepish
reserved
reticent
introverted
retiring
self-effacing
withdrawn
timorous
mousy
nervous
insecure
unconfident
inhibited
repressed
self-conscious
embarrassed